# Using robust linear methods from python module "statsmodels" with weights?

Tags: python, matlab, linear-regression, statsmodels

I have some data,y with errors, y_err, measured at x. I need to fit a straight line to this mimicking some code from matlab specifically the fit method with robust "on" and giving the weights as 1/yerr. The matlab documentation says it uses the bisquare method (also know as the TukeyBiweight method). My code so far is..

```
    rlm_model = sm.RLM(y, x, M=sm.robust.norms.TukeyBiweight())
    rlm_results = rlm_model.fit()
    print rlm_results.params
```

however I need to find a way of including weights derived from yerr. 
Hope people can help, this is the first time I have tried to used the statsmodel module.

In response to the first answer:
I tried;

```
y=y*(yerr)
x=x*(yerr)

x=sm.add_constant(x, prepend=False)
rlm_model = sm.RLM(y, x, M=sm.robust.norms.TukeyBiweight())
results=rlm_model.fit()
```

but sadly this doesnt match the matlab function.

Comment: try `y = y / yerr`, divide by yerr, the weight is the inverse. And you have to add the constant before you divide x by yerr, `x / yerr`. The constant also needs to be weighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weights reflecting heteroscedasticity, that is unequal variance across observations, are not yet supported by statsmodels RLM.

As a workaround, you can divide your y and x by yerr in the call to RLM.

I think, in analogy to weighted least squares, the parameter estimates, their standard errors and other statistics are still correct in this case. But I haven't checked yet.

as reference:

Carroll, Raymond J., and David Ruppert. "Robust estimation in heteroscedastic linear models." The annals of statistics (1982): 429-441.

They also estimate the variance function, but for fixed weights 1/sigma_i the optimization just uses

(y_i - x_i beta) / sigma_i

The weights 1/sigma_i will only be relative weights and will still be multiplied with a robust estimate of the scale of the errors.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect your tips. Thanks for the reference as well since I think the problem stems from my lack of understanding of these sort of methods.